# A question about breakpoints

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to prove that the first class of breakpoints(That is the right limit and left limit exist)on a function on an interval is countable.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: "That is the right limit and left limit exist" **but they are not the same**.

Answer (score 0):

Can you think of a set from which you can always embed a member inside the interval created by left and right limits?

Even better, if you can choose a countable set in above...then a proof by contradiction awaits you. :)